# Show some text in android application

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I want to display a some text to the user if they perform some action. I tried using alert kind of thing, but I don't like it. I just want to display a message.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, please refer to [How  to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in order to formulate a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you want exactly, but you can use `Toast` feature available in `Android`, as shown below:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message here...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want the message to displayed and gone in specific time then use `TOAST`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Messsage here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or if you want tot show message that has to be hide on user click then use `alertDialog`

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

 alertDialog.setMessage("Alert Message here");

 alertDialog.show();
```

You can have more function with that message like OK button,etc.For details check out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Notification.

Check this : [Android Notifications.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AlertDialog to display message

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

 // Setting Dialog Title
 alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

 // Setting Dialog Message
 alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to Android Application");

 // Setting Icon to Dialog
 alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

 // Setting OK Button
 alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
        {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 });

            // Showing Alert Message
 alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing the text in android use `Toast`It is similar like printf or system.out.println in other programming languages for displaying some text.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some text to textView wich u r created.

```
textView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
textView.setText("Your text");
```

whenever you don't need that just set visibility to gone!

```
or use Toast or alertDialog.
```